# How does the blender-4-dental sculpt tool work?

Tags: sculpting

Does anyone know how this brush works?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I started using blender on and off when my former boss got the blender-4-dental add-on for our lab and told me to use it and i really like how this brush automatically remeshes specific areas, problem is the add-on is pretty expensive and i'm just interested in this function.

I know there is a remesh tool in blender but i don't like how it changes the overall shape of my object (my pc can't handle complex topology so i have to keep it low) plus i only need a remesh in certain areas.

I've tried to make my own add on through scripting myself but i just don't know how to make that brush...

Comment: Please take proper screenshots of your screen instead of photographs. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: This is my Lab's PC, me not having the add-on is my problem...

Comment: @Lisa I'm quite sure even your lab's PC is capable of making proper screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Check Dyntopo functionality that can be enabled in the Sidebar in Sculpt mode:

[image]

Comment: Glad I saw you posted the answer before I finished mine, saved me some work  But you don't need the sidebar, just check it at the top.

Comment: I don't do much sculpting myself... Yep, One can clearly see it in the top Tool Settings bar and it must also be in the Tool tab of the Properties Editor somewhere.